# Combobox index and value of non continued index

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0

Not Sure how to explain the situation but its something like this

I am fetching `(INT)category_id` and `(VARCHAR)categories_code` from database and trying to push data inside Combobox using `Index(category_id)` and `Value(categories_code)`. Now my problem starts when database doesn't have continued number index Eg. 0,1,3 and it throws Exception

```
InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index
```

My Code is something like this

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM `category`";
productCategory.Items.Insert(0, "--- SELECT ---");
using (MySqlDataReader mysqlData = con.Select(query))
{
     if (mysqlData.HasRows)
     {
          while (mysqlData.Read())
          {
              int id = mysqlData.GetInt32("category_id");
              String name = mysqlData.GetString("category_code");
              productCategory.Items.Insert(id, name);
           }
      }
 }
```

What can be the expected solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter instead ?

```
int i = 1;
using (MySqlDataReader mysqlData = con.Select(query))
{
     if (mysqlData.HasRows)
     {
          while (mysqlData.Read())
          {
              int id = mysqlData.GetInt32("category_id");
              String name = mysqlData.GetString("category_code");
              productCategory.Items.Insert(i++, name);
           }
      }
 }
```

or why don't you just use `Add` method?

```
 productCategory.Items.Add(name);
```

If you want to get category id of selected item, then you should use a class for that.Create a class that has two properties, `CategoryId` and `CategoryCode`. Then have a `List<YourClass>` populate it, set the `DataSource`, `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties of combobox.

```
productCategory.DataSource = yourList;
productCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryCode"; 
productCategory.ValueMember = "CategoryId";
```

Comment: Going to try your last suggestion.. will update in a while.. thanks